# KeyError in Python 3 Dictionary, but it's returning the current value

Tags: search, dictionary, python-3.x, io, tuples

So I have this file with these values:

```
AFG,13,0,0,2
ALG,15,5,2,8
ARG,40,18,24,28
```

Stored into a dictionary like this:

```
{'ARG': (40, 18, 24, 28), 'ALG': (15, 5, 2, 8), 'AFG': (13, 0, 0, 2)}
```

I have a function that has the user punch in the key, and it should return the tuple with the numbers in it.

However, if I were to type in, say, AFG, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\username\Dropbox\Programming\Python\Project3.py", line 131, in <module>
main()
File "C:\Users\username\Dropbox\Programming\Python\Project3.py", line 110, in main
findMedals(countryDictionary, MedalDictionary)
File "C:\Users\username\Dropbox\Programming\Python\Project3.py", line 88, in findMedals
answer.append([medalDict[medalCount]])
KeyError: (13, 0, 0, 2)
```

As you can see, the KeyError gives out the correct value for the inputted key, but why is it still complaining about it?  Doesn't KeyError mean the key didn't exist?

My code:

```
def findMedals(countryDict, medalDict):

    search_str = input('What is the country you want information on? ')

 for code, medalCount in medalDict.items():
    if search_str in code:
        answer.append([medalDict[medalCount]])
    else:
        answer = ['No Match Found']
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line:

```
answer.append([medalDict[medalCount]])
```

You are iterating over medalDict with `for code, medalCount in medalDict.items():`. This already assigns `medalCount` to the value associated with the key `code`. Your dict doesn't have a key represented by the tuple of medals. Therefore, it errors when you ask for `medalDict[medalCount]`.

You can fix this by:

```
answer.append([medalCount])
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I changed the code to:

    for code, medalCount in medalDict.items():
        if search_str in code:
            answer.append([medalCount])
        else:
            answer = ['No Match Found']'

Now I'm getting this error:
    TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

I know that usually shows up when a function call is missing parentheses, but it appears I have the ones I need?